# Storing function pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

The following uses a simple function pointer, but what if I want to store that function pointer?  In that case, what would the variable declaration look like?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double operation(double (*functocall)(double), double wsum);
double get_unipolar(double);
double get_bipolar(double);

int main()
{
    double k = operation(get_bipolar, 2); // how to store get_bipolar?
    cout << k;
    return 0;
}
double operation(double (*functocall)(double), double wsum)
{
    double g = (*functocall)(wsum);
    return g;
}
double get_unipolar(double wsum)
{
    double threshold = 3;
    if (wsum > threshold)
        return threshold;
    else
        return threshold;
}
double get_bipolar(double wsum)
{
    double threshold = 4;
    if (wsum > threshold)
        return threshold;
    else
        return threshold;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You code is almost done already, you just seem to call it improperly, it should be simply

```
double operation(double (*functocall)(double), double wsum)
{
    double g;
    g = functocall(wsum);
    return g;
}
```

If you want to have a variable, it's declared in the same way

```
double (*functocall2)(double) = get_bipolar;
```

or when already declared

```
functocall2 = get_bipolar;
```

gives you a variable called `functocall2` which is referencing get_bipolar, calling it by simply doing

```
functocall2(mydouble);
```

or passing it to operation by

```
operation(functocall2, wsum);
```

Comment: yesssss   that's what i wanted .. exactly  i wanted to save the get_bipolar in a variable .. so i can use that variable again in some other place or even make an array of it

Comment: i declared the functocall2 at the header file , how the assign would look like in a cpp file ????????????

Comment: Simply `functocall2 = get_bipolar;` just like any other assignment.

Answer (score 5):

You already (almost) have it in your code:

```
double (*functocall)(double) = &get_bipolar;
```

This defines a function pointer named `functocall` which points to `get_bipolar`.

Comment: shouldn't it be simply `... = get_bipolar;` without the `&`?

Comment: like this ??

double (*functocall)(double) = &get_bipolar;
k=operation(???,2); // then what to put here ??

Comment: @roe - Using the & is definitely allowed and generally preferred by those in the "explicit is better than implicit" camp

Comment: I think the ampersand only worked in C (and still was optional), right?

Comment: @Manuel: are you sure about that, it feels like functions are by their very definition pointers (to code) already.

Comment: @roe - Yes, I'm completely sure. @fortran - C++ has C compatibility

Comment: @ismail - Maybe you should put angle brackets in those #includes ?

Comment: @ manuel
nope i intentionally did it this way cause of the website <pre> tags 

but i think i wrote it in wrong place i'm sorry :) 

thanks alot this website and you people are amazing really !!

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef double (*func_t)(double); 
func_t to_be_used = get_bipolar
```

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef double (*PtrFunc)(double); 

PtrFunc ptrBipolar = get_bipolar;


OR


typedef double (Func)(double); 

Func *ptrBipolar = get_bipolar;
```

which ever you are comfortable to use.

Comment: Though when typedefing function types, I'd name them "Func" instead of "PtrFunc".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at boost function, it's a header only library that tidies things up  a little (IMHO):
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/function.html

```
typedef boost::function<double (double)> func_t;
func_t to_be_used = &get_bipolar;
```

(NB: different syntax required for VC6)

Comment: In the OP's case this will add some overhead to every call without any  additional benefits

Comment: There are advantages and disadvantages to boost function. The overhead is likely to be insignificant in the OP's use case, the additional benefit is in tidier code and greater extendibility. Seemed worth mentioning in a forum like this so readers can see what's available.

Answer (score 0):

```
double (*foo)(double);
```

where `foo` is the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a typedef:

```
 typedef double (*MyFunc)(double);
 MyFunc ptr_func = &get_bipolar;
 (*ptr_func)(0.0);


double operation(MyFunc functocall, double wsum)
{
    double g;
    g = (*functocall)(wsum);
    return g;
}
```

May I recommend also the identity template trick:

```
template<class T>
class Id
{
    typedef T type;
};

Id<double(double)>::type * ptr_func = &get_bipolar;
MyFunc func = &get_bipolar;
(*ptr_func)(0.0);


double operation(Id<double(double)>::type * functocall, double wsum)
{
    double g;
    g = (*functocall)(wsum);
    return g;
}
```